# How to clear the branch names from TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

In my git repo origin, i used to have the branches called "test" and "master". I removed the branch "test" from origin. And pushed a new branch "TEST". Notice that I basically removed the "test" with all small case and added a branch with all caps "TEST".

I ran "git fetch --prune" on my local machine. And then removed the branch test ("git branch -D test"). So, in my local i now have TEST and master branches. And i only see these 2 branches when i run "git branch" using git bash.

But, the issue i am seeing here is that, tortoise git is still showing the "test" branch that i already removed from my origin and local. Please help me in getting rid of the "test" branch from tortoise git as well. This is important for me, as there are other team members that use only tortoise git and not git bash and they see the same issue. So, i should atleast solve this issue for them.

Go to the directory of a git repo. Right click in the directory and you will see this menu.
[image]

Click on Git pull. You will see the following dialogue.
[image]

As you can see above, the Remote branch dropdown still displays "test"

if we click on git push from the first screenshot, this dialogue will appear.

[image]

And the remote dropdown in this case displays only "test" and not "TEST". Because of this, when people push this way, it is resulting in creation of a new branch called "test" in the origin, which is not intended.

I know we can manually type "TEST" for the remote branch before pushing. But, it would be nice if the "test" goes away which will prevent people from accidentally pushing to the wrong branch "test".

Comment: What is the output from the command `git branch --all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Selective removal: Mousehover an entry and then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.
- Removing all settings: Go to TortoiseGit settings -> Saved Data and hit the appropriate clear button (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-saved-data)